# Handle optional url parameter in Django unit test case

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, django-tests

I have created a Dynamic Url with optional parameter

e.g., If my url is as **www.example.com/getTest/1/** 
Now this `1` in url is optional , to handle this in views I have used None like

```
def function(request, id=None):
   pass
```

Thus if there is no id in URL then still the function works for me.
But I am facing issue while testing this in unit cases.
if I use url as `url = reverse('yescourse:academypage_url', args=[None])` it gives me the error

`NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'academypage_url' with arguments '('new', None)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.`

So Please Tell me how I can handle these optional url in Test cases or in Reverse.

**Edit :**

```
 url(r'^getTest/(?P<action>\w+)/(?P<id>\d*)$', 'app.views.create_edit_academypage', name='academypage_url'),
```

Comment: What happens if you do `args=[]`? And can you please show your urls.py?

Comment: @DanielRoseman Still gets the same error `with arguments '()' ` and for urls I have updated my question

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You made the view function's `id` parameter optional, but it's not optional in the url pattern. You firsty need to rewrite your pattern as :

```
r'^getTest/(?P<action>\w+)/(?P<id>\d+)?$'
```

=> the whole 'id' sub-pattern is optional, but if it's not it must match one or more numerics.

Once done, you can reverse the url by not passing any of the `args` nor `kwargs` arguments:

```
url = reverse('yescourse:academypage_url')
```

or by passing an empty list

```
url = reverse('yescourse:academypage_url', args=[])
```

or by passing `None`

```
url = reverse('yescourse:academypage_url', args=None)
```

but **not** by passing a list containing `None`.

Comment: Thanks It works for me , just one more question what if my both parameters in url are optional , then what will be my url pattern , will `/` replaces with `?` too ?

Comment: If you want to make both parameters optionals (which means you can have either no action nor id, no action and an id, an action but no id), your pattern should be `r'^getTest(?:/(?P<action>\w+))?(?:/(?P<id>\d+))?$'`, your function's signature `(request, action=None, id=None)`, **and** you'll probably have to only the use the "named arguments" (`kwargs`) version only for `reverse()` and the `url` templatetag - but it's always safer to use this form since it lets you reorganize your url patterns freely.